# Angular сбрасывает состояние checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

есть директива

```
app.directive( "ngRestoreState",  function ( ) {
 return function ( scope, $input, attrs ) {
  //...

  if ( restore [ id ] === true ) {
   // $input.click(); - work
   // $input.prop( "checked", true ); - not work
  }
  //...
 }

} );
```

если использовать `$input.click()` то все работает, если то `$input.prop( "checked", true )` checkbox всегда false, проблема воспроизводится только если установлена директива ngModel, как я понял оно где то сбрасывает состояние checkbox, как это обойти? и где оно сбрасывает и когда?

Нашел решениe, но это костыль

```
attrs.$observe("ngModel", function(value) {
 setTimeout( function (argument) {
  $input.prop( "checked", true );
 }, 0 );

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение

```
app.directive( "ngRestoreState",  function ( ) {

      return {
      restrict: 'A', 
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; 
        ngModel.$setViewValue ( true );
        ngModel.$render();

      }
    };
```

или переопредилить рендерер

```
 ngModel.$render = function () {
      element.prop( "checked", true );
 }
```

ответ почему тут https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1398